# How do I use an online page source with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Started Python a week ago actually, but I desperately need to have this project done as it will help make things easier at the office.

I have a code that looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html_doc ="""


"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
dev = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'title'})
```

It gets the job done as long as I am inserting the pages source code inside

```
html_doc="""

""""
```

What do I replace it with so I can use a link instead?

I know URLLIB2-3 can get the job done but I am having a hard time understanding it, please help

Comment: Do you know how the world wide web works? I mean at a very high level. If not, you will need to learn about the request/response model. This will help make using urllib understandable. You can also consider using [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead.

Comment: One thing to be aware: neither `urllib` nor `requests` is able to handle dynamic content. If the data in the page you are scraping is modified at all by JavaScript when running in a browser, then you will need to find another solution such as `selenium`.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned you could take a look at [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) it is comparable to `urllib` and will work in general the same way as shown in the example.

#### Very basic example (requests)

This will request an url and get some content as response back - These content could be processed wit beautifulsoup and will give you a list of `<a>` in all `<h3>`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?genres=action'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

soup.select('h3 a')
```

##### Example urllib

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?genres=action').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

soup.select('h3 a')
```

#### Output

```
[<a href="/title/tt7462410/">Das Rad der Zeit</a>,
 <a href="/title/tt11126994/">Arcane</a>,
 <a href="/title/tt10160804/">Hawkeye</a>,
 <a href="/title/tt1267295/">Cowboy Bebop</a>,
 <a href="/title/tt7991608/">Red Notice</a>,...]
```